# Spring webflux api rest - not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring, spring-webflux

Creé un servicio súper sencillo, al momento de llamar un endpoint get me retorna un 404, no estoy trabajando con una base de datos.

- En el properties sólo tengo la línea:

  ```
  server.port=8082
  ```
- La interfaz:

  ```
    public interface IPersonaRepository {

    Mono<Persona> registrar(Persona persona);
    Mono<Persona> modificar(Persona persona);
    Flux<Persona> listar();
    Mono<Persona> listarPorId(Integer id);
    Mono<Void> eliminar(Integer Id);
  ```

  }
- La implementación de la interfaz, le puse como reporitorio, copié solamente el override del método de interés

  ```
     @Repository
        public class PersonaImplements implements IPersonaRepository{


        private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonaImplements.class);
    @Override
        public Flux<Persona> listar() {
            List<Persona> personas = new ArrayList<>();
            personas.add( new Persona(1,"Hablando Claro"));
            personas.add( new Persona(2,"Coreano Mochilero"));
            personas.add( new Persona(3,"Tía Liv"));
            personas.add( new Persona(4,"BN Periodismo"));
            personas.add( new Persona(5,"Café con JJ"));

            return Flux.fromIterable(personas);
        }
  ```
- Controlador

  ```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/personas")
    public class PersonaController {
        private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonaController.class);

        @Autowired
    private IPersonaRepository personaRepository;

    @GetMapping
    public Flux<Persona> listar()
    {
       return personaRepository.listar();

    }
  ```

  }
- dependencias del pom.xml

  ```
       <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
                <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
  ```
- Al momento de hacer la llamada  localhost:8082/personas   obtengo

  ```
        {
            "timestamp": "2022-05-06T20:06:53.814+00:00",
            "path": "/personas",
            "status": 404,
            "error": "Not Found",
            "message": null,
            "requestId": "bfe1823a-1"
        }
  ```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

He recreado tu proyecto, a continuación dejo el código, asegurate de que solo este corriendo tu aplicación en ese puerto.

Clase User utilizando [lombok](/questions/tagged/lombok)

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {

private Long id;
private String name;

public User(Long id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}
}


@Repository
public class UserRepository implements UserInterface {
    @Override
    public Flux<User> listar() {
        List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
        userList.add(new User(2L, "Hablando Claro"));
        userList.add(new User(3L, "Hablando"));
        return Flux.fromIterable(userList);
    }
}

public interface UserInterface {

    Flux<User> listar();
}


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/personas")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserInterface userRepository;

    @GetMapping
    public Flux<User> listar()
    {

        return userRepository.listar();

    }
}
```

Resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]